# Delete rows older than 30 minutes in MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, sql

In my table `mytable`. I have a column named `session_time (float)` where I store the time in microseconds when the row was added (I use the PHP function `microtime(true)` to get a float). How can I delete all rows from my table `mytable` which are older than 20 minutes?

I already tried something like this:

```
DELETE FROM mytable WHERE session_time < DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1800 SECOND)
```

But this deletes all rows!

Comment: How large is the table?  I would be inclined to go with a partitioning approach and drop partitions, if this is a frequently updated table and such an approach meets your needs.

Comment: DATE_SUB will use MySQL's DATETIME/TIMESTAMP format not PHP's microtime.  Why not use DATETIME instead of a float for session_time?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

UPDATED...

Instead of using php `microtime(true)` , you should use MySQL function NOW(). Delete the old column, and make a new one :

```
ALTER TABLE your_table ADD session_time DATETIME NOT NULL DEFAULT NOW();
```

Now when you add a row, it's session_time will be set to the current time automatically, and you do not need to insert any value for session_time.

Now for deleting all rows older than 30 minutes, use :

```
DELETE FROM your_table WHERE TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE,session_time,NOW()) > 30;
```

Comment: This is the best approach, as you're just asking for your site to break later if you're mixing timestamp computation between PHP and mysql. If you ever put the DB on a remote node, for example, the timestamp would be a little off if using microtime() to set the time but NOW() to compare it. Since they're testing for microseconds, a little off is a big deal.

Comment: @JoshfromQaribou Yes that's true. If we do all this in the database itself, then we use the Database server's time, so there will not be any difference between timestamps.

Comment: Yes, it is what I recommended in comments.  Microseconds is their storage but they are comparing against 30 minutes, so microseconds is unnecessary in this case.  I don't know their reasoning for microseconds, assuming the OP has one.  You could also use PHP to fill the query so it is relying on the same clock if microseconds does matter as I put in my answer below.

Comment: @Devon Yes that can also be a way of achieving this. But generally, I prefer handling most of the time functions through MySQL. It prevents my script from having unnecessary overhead (even if a little).

Comment: Really no overhead with using PHP compared to MySQL in this. The PHP time() - 1800 might even be faster in this case than DATE_SUB.  I do agree that you should take advantage of MySQL storage types though, mostly for manipulation and readability later on.

Comment: @Devon yeah that is also possible. Yes, using MySQL's storage types does make the code neat.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
DELETE FROM  myTABLE  WHERE session_time < (now() - interval 30 minute)
```

I didn't  test it.  I think it shoud work as well.

Answer (score 0):

PHP `microtime()` uses unix timestamp format, not the `DATETIME` format.  If you are storing things like that, you could use PHP to fill the query or use MySQL's [`unix_timestamp()` function](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_unix-timestamp).

For PHP, it would be as simple as:

```
$query = 'DELETE FROM mytable WHERE session_time < '.time() - 1800;
```

I would recommend just using the DATETIME format on `session_time` though, you should take advantage of MySQL’s storage types.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you're comparing a microsecond value generated in PHP, to a timestamp value generated in mysql. There's a few things that could go wrong here, since you may not actually be comparing time to time but time to float, or your PHP app is using a different clock than your mysql.

Since you're doing the comparison in SQL, you should save the session_time value based on SQL too. This is a good place for a default value, e.g.:

```
mysql> create table mytable ( id int not null, session_time timestamp default now() );
```

Comment: Time differences aren't likely to make much of a difference with unix time since it is all in UTC.

Comment: UTC isn't the point. They will if it's a remote node. You calculate a timestamp in the PHP code, commit your transaction on the PHP server with the timestamp you calculated there, then send that to the DB server. There will also be a slight difference in the time set on the php and the db server clocks.
You're also ignoring column typing differences from the value calculated by PHP. There's a hundred different ways you could lose microsecond-level accuracy here.

Comment: Yes, I agree, but for this case, the comparison is 30 minutes not microseconds, even though the storage is microseconds.